# Creating a submenu in the explorer-shell-extention?

Tags: windows, registry, explorer, submenu, shell-extensions

I created a small script that changes a filename (replacing spaces with `_`, etc.). I'm controlling this script with parameters.

Now I'd like to include that into my explorer-shell-extention, so I tried to add the following registry entries:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\edit filname method a\command
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\edit filname method b\command
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\edit filname method c\command
```

and so on.

It's working fine but I'd like to pack all those methods together into a submenu.
Kinda like the "open with" option. Is that possible?

Comment: [Creating Static Cascading Menus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can just edit this to expand your needs.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;           TOOLS MENU

            [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\contexttools_anchor]
                "MUIVerb"="SendTo Tools"
                "Icon"="...YOUR PATH...\\files\\Tools.ico"
            "ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="*\\ContextMenus\\contexttools"
                ; "Extended"=""
; __________________________________________________________________________ >

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\ContextMenus\contexttools\Shell\001cmd]
        "MUIVerb"="Notepad 2"
        "Icon"="...YOUR PATH...\\Tools\\app1.exe"

            [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\ContextMenus\contexttools\Shell\001cmd\command]
                @="...YOUR PATH...\\Tools\\app1.exe \"%1\""
; __________________________________________________________________________ >
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\ContextMenus\contexttools\Shell\005seperator]
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000008
; __________________________________________________________________________ >

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\ContextMenus\contexttools\Shell\006cmd]
        "MUIVerb"="Hash Compare"
        "Icon"="...YOUR PATH...\\Tools\\app2.exe"

            [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\ContextMenus\contexttools\Shell\006cmd\command]
                @="...YOUR PATH...\\Tools\\app2.exe \"%1\""
; __________________________________________________________________________ >
```